How to convert .heic files to .jpg using ImageMagick?
I'm starting now to use ImageMagick.
Using the convert command I can convert .jpg to .png files and also .webp to .jpg
$ convert  prova.webp prova.jpg

If I try to convert .heic I obtain an error:
~$ convert  prova.heic prova.jpg
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `prova.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3229.

Is it due to an old version of ImageMagick? My version is:
ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25
Help, please!

I find the default version in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS of ImageMagick: LANG=C apt policy imagemagick outputs
imagemagick:   Installed: 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.04.5+esm1 and it can convert heic files for me with the command that you show. Have you installed the package ubuntu-restricted-extras ? Are you sure that your heic files are healthy?

I converted a entire folder: for file in *.heic; do heif-convert $file ${file/%.heic/.jpg}; done  #case matters

By the way, I can also show heic files with gimp. Please check if you can do that too. I think 'gimpuses the same libraries asconvert`.

Thanks for all your answers and suggestions.
Running the command suggested by @sudodus I obtain axactly the same ImageMagick version.
With Gimp I can see and convert the files using a script that is rather complex (for my level).
ubuntu-restricted-extras are installed with an error removing old packages
libdvd-pkg: apt-get check failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...
Any more suggestion?

I thank @oldfred too. I tried to install heif-convert but I have some wrong packages and the install command suggests to wait for the new version 1.16.2-0ubuntu2~focal to be released shortly.

Try sudo apt-get install -f; Read about more options in man apt-get. It may help you solve the problem with broken packages.

How did you try to install heif-convert? I suggest that you try sudo apt install libheif-examples (at least in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS).

This says it is available in all recent versions of Ubuntu. And is part of libheif-examples as sudodus suggests. https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/mantic/man1/heif-convert.1.html Did not know I did not install it directly as I have a long list of apps I install from a script and/or backup from previous install.
